# How to prevent the spring boot application starting for each test classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I know this question is an old one but I could not solve the problem in my case. When I am running test classes spring boot application is starting for each test class. I am having bellow annotations in my test class files. I want to start the application only once for all test classes

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
```

Comment: Integration tests should load a context (and of course it takes time), but the loaded context is [reused](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-ctx-management) in other tests. Test more things in unit tests if possible

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this using a parent BaseTest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class BaseTest {

}
```

I use SpringRunner but SpringJUnit4ClassRunner should be ok too

Comment: I tried the same but not working. For every test class, spring boot starting the server and tables are getting created/altered in H2 in-memory database. I am using version 2.2.2.

Comment: If I remove @MockBean from my test classes, working fine. But I want to mock DB calls response. Is there any way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

By using the `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` you are telling spring boot to start a server on each class instantiation.

To avoid this, use a parent class that all testclasses extend from.

Comment: I tried the same but not working. For every test class, spring boot starting the server and tables are getting created/altered in H2 in-memory database. I am using version 2.2.2.

Comment: If I remove @MockBean from my test classes, working fine. But I want to mock DB calls response. Is there any way to solve my issue?

Comment: post your entire code and describe what it is you are trying to do, im not going to help anyone that hasn't given me the full picture. there is no `@MockBean` in posted code. You asked a question and posted that little piece of code. We answered your question with the correct answer. If it doesn't work then you need to post the relevant information and ask a correct question.